# Tensorflow Error (Python): Failed to convert object of type <class 'dict'> to Tensor

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

As part of a course on Udemy, I am trying to create a linear classifier that will predict whether a person makes greater than or less than 50K a year. Unfortunately, I am getting this tensorflow error: `Failed to convert object of type <class 'dict'> to Tensor.`

Here is the error:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    526     try:
--> 527       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
    528     except TypeError:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    526     try:
--> 527       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
    528     except TypeError:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py in as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding)
     60     raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
---> 61                     (bytes_or_text,))
     62 

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got {'income_bracket': <tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:14' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-56c52ca792f4> in <module>
----> 1 model.train(input_fn=input_func, steps=5000)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    352 
    353       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 354       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    355       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    356       return self

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1205       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1206     else:
-> 1207       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1208 
   1209   def _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1235       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
   1236       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(
-> 1237           features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
   1238       global_step_tensor = training_util.get_global_step(g)
   1239       return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
   1193 
   1194     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
-> 1195     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
   1196     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
   1197 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/linear.py in _model_fn(features, labels, mode, config)
    382           partitioner=partitioner,
    383           config=config,
--> 384           sparse_combiner=sparse_combiner)
    385 
    386     super(LinearClassifier, self).__init__(

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/linear.py in _linear_model_fn(features, labels, mode, head, feature_columns, optimizer, partitioner, config, sparse_combiner)
    213         labels=labels,
    214         optimizer=optimizer,
--> 215         logits=logits)
    216 
    217 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/head.py in create_estimator_spec(self, features, mode, logits, labels, optimizer, train_op_fn, regularization_losses)
    237           self._create_tpu_estimator_spec(
    238               features, mode, logits, labels, optimizer, train_op_fn,
--> 239               regularization_losses))
    240       return tpu_estimator_spec.as_estimator_spec()
    241     except NotImplementedError:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/head.py in _create_tpu_estimator_spec(self, features, mode, logits, labels, optimizer, train_op_fn, regularization_losses)
   1207       (training_loss, unreduced_loss, weights, processed_labels) = (
   1208           self.create_loss(
-> 1209               features=features, mode=mode, logits=logits, labels=labels))
   1210       if regularization_losses:
   1211         regularization_loss = math_ops.add_n(regularization_losses)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/head.py in create_loss(***failed resolving arguments***)
   1108     logits = ops.convert_to_tensor(logits)
   1109     labels = _check_dense_labels_match_logits_and_reshape(
-> 1110         labels=labels, logits=logits, expected_labels_dimension=1)
   1111     if self._label_vocabulary is not None:
   1112       labels = lookup_ops.index_table_from_tensor(

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/head.py in _check_dense_labels_match_logits_and_reshape(labels, logits, expected_labels_dimension)
    303         'returns labels.')
    304   with ops.name_scope(None, 'labels', (labels, logits)) as scope:
--> 305     labels = sparse_tensor.convert_to_tensor_or_sparse_tensor(labels)
    306     if isinstance(labels, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    307       raise ValueError(

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/sparse_tensor.py in convert_to_tensor_or_sparse_tensor(value, dtype, name)
    277     return value
    278   return ops.internal_convert_to_tensor(
--> 279       value, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    280 
    281 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
   1144 
   1145     if ret is None:
-> 1146       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1147 
   1148     if ret is NotImplemented:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    227                                          as_ref=False):
    228   _ = as_ref
--> 229   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    230 
    231 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
    206   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
    207       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
--> 208           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
    209   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    210   const_tensor = g.create_op(

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    529       raise TypeError("Failed to convert object of type %s to Tensor. "
    530                       "Contents: %s. Consider casting elements to a "
--> 531                       "supported type." % (type(values), values))
    532     tensor_proto.string_val.extend(str_values)
    533     return tensor_proto

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'dict'> to Tensor. Contents: {'income_bracket': <tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:14' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>}. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
census_data = pd.read_csv("census_data.csv")
census_data["income_bracket"] = 
census_data["income_bracket"].apply(lambda x: 0 if x==" <=50K" else 1)
y_census_data = pd.DataFrame(census_data["income_bracket"])
x_census_data = census_data.drop("income_bracket", axis=1)
test_data = {
    "y":None,
    "x":None
}

train_data = {
    "y":None,
    "x":None
}
train_data["x"], test_data["x"], train_data["y"], test_data["y"] = train_test_split(
    x_census_data, 
    y_census_data,  
    test_size=0.33
)
def feature_column_prefill(col_name):
    return_val = 
tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    col_name, 
    list(census_data[col_name].unique())
)
return return_val
workclass = feature_column_prefill("workclass")
education = feature_column_prefill("education")
marital_status = feature_column_prefill("marital_status")
occupation = feature_column_prefill("occupation")
relationship = feature_column_prefill("relationship")
race = feature_column_prefill("race")
gender = feature_column_prefill("gender")
native_country = feature_column_prefill("native_country")

age = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("age")
education_num = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("education_num")
capital_gain = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("capital_gain")
capital_loss = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("capital_loss")
hours_per_week = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("hours_per_week")
feat_cols = [ age, workclass, education, education_num, marital_status, 
 occupation, relationship, race, gender, capital_gain, capital_loss, 
 hours_per_week, native_country ]
input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    x=train_data["x"],
    y=train_data["y"],
    batch_size=10, 
    num_epochs=1000, 
    shuffle=True
)
model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
    feature_columns=feat_cols, 
    n_classes=2
)
model.train(input_fn=input_func, steps=5000)
```

Here is a small sample of the csv file:

```
28, Private, Bachelors,13, Married-civ-spouse, Prof-specialty, Wife, Black, Female,0,0,40, Cuba, <=50K
37, Private, Masters,14, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Wife, White, Female,0,0,40, United-States, <=50K
49, Private, 9th,5, Married-spouse-absent, Other-service, Not-in-family, Black, Female,0,0,16, Jamaica, <=50K
52, Self-emp-not-inc, HS-grad,9, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male,0,0,45, United-States, >50K
31, Private, Masters,14, Never-married, Prof-specialty, Not-in-family, White, Female,14084,0,50, United-States, >50K
42, Private, Bachelors,13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male,5178,0,40, United-States, >50K
37, Private, Some-college,10, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, Black, Male,0,0,80, United-States, >50K
```

I am pretty stuck so if someone could help that would be great. Thanks a lot.

I expect the model to start training, however, I get the error.

Comment: The fact that the error references `{'income_bracket': ...}` suggests that your `y` data is in the wrong format. What's the reason for converting it to a DataFrame on this line: `y_census_data = pd.DataFrame(census_data["income_bracket"])
` ? Have you tried it without that conversion?

Comment: I did this because I am using a tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn() to create the input function for the estimator.